# How to automatically create a list for @SuiteClasses

Tags: java, junit4

I need a possibility to run a subset of my JUnit tests cases during Maven build process. I've decided to use JUnit categories for this purposes. I've created two marker interfaces: `UnitTest` and `IntegrationTest` and assigned them to the bunch of my JUnit test cases. Now I need to create a test suite for them:

```
package ru.hive.parser;

import org.junit.experimental.categories.Categories;
import org.junit.experimental.categories.Categories.IncludeCategory;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Suite.SuiteClasses;

import ru.hive.test.UnitTest;

@RunWith(Categories.class)
@IncludeCategory(UnitTest.class)
@SuiteClasses({ SomeClass.class })
public class ParserTestSuite {

}
```

The problem is `@SuiteClasses` annotation in which I need to list all the classes I want to be in test suite and I have A LOT (more than 100) of such classes and the number is growing. I will be nice if I have the way to build the list of classes automatically. I've read all the question here on stackoverflow that some sort similar to my own, but none of the answers fit my needs since I need to use `@RunWith(Categories.class)` instead of other test runners. Any ideas how to realize this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maven is able to use the categories runner. See here: http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/junit.html

You could also use the [classpath suite](http://johanneslink.net/projects/cpsuite.jsp) and modify it to use the categories runner for tests found on the classpath (if it doesn't do so already?).

Generating a long list of `@SuiteClasses` doesn't seem worth the effort.